# Use conditions in other columns and numeric index of loop-columns in loop/lapply/mutate across

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 1  1  1  2 NA  1  0
 2  0  0  2  1 NA  1
 3  1  0  2  1  1 NA
 4  0  1  2  0  0 NA
 5  1  0  2  1  1 NA
 6  0  0  2 NA  1  1
 7  0  1  2 NA  1 NA
 8  0  0  2 NA  1 NA
 9  1  0  2  1  1  1
10  0  1  2  1  1 NA
```

dput is as follows (EDIT: corrected):

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                     V2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 
                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V4 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                        1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA
                                                                                                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm looking for code that lets `V1:V3` unchanged. For `V4:V6` I want to apply something like the following `if_else`-statement:

`if_else(df$V1 == 0 & df$V2 == 1 & "index of loop columns" > df$V3, 1, "do nothing")`

So for example, for rows 4/7/10$V6 the `NA` would be changed to `1`, because the following statement would be true:

`if_else(df$V1 == 0 & df$V2 == 1 & numerical index [3] > df$V3 [2], 1, df$V6`

The remaining rows should stay the same, as should `V4` and `V5`, because there indexes are `1` and `2` and therefore never bigger than `V3`.

I produced a few dead ends with for loops and lapply, as I can't figure out how to get the specific numeric index for the `>` operator into my code. I would be grateful for any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Just clarifying - you consider the "numerical index" of V4 is 1, V5 is 2, and V6 is 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly - so the index should start at the columns I want to loop over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works. It's a little hard to tell because the `dput()` doesn't match the printed data in your question...

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
  V2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V4 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
  1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1   1  1  2 NA  1 NA
# 2   0  0  2  1 NA  1
# 3   1  0  2  1  1 NA
# 4   0  1  2 NA  1 NA
# 5   1  0  2  1 NA NA
# 6   0  0  2 NA  1  1
# 7   0  1  2 NA  1 NA
# 8   0  0  2 NA  1 NA
# 9   1  0  2  1  1  1
# 10  0  1  2  1  1 NA

library(dplyr)
cols_to_loop = c("V4", "V5", "V6")

for (i in seq_along(cols_to_loop)) {
  df = mutate(df, across(cols_to_loop[i], ~if_else(V1 == 0 & V2 == 1 & i > V3, 1L, .) ))
}

df
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1   1  1  2 NA  1 NA
# 2   0  0  2  1 NA  1
# 3   1  0  2  1  1 NA
# 4   0  1  2 NA  1  1
# 5   1  0  2  1 NA NA
# 6   0  0  2 NA  1  1
# 7   0  1  2 NA  1  1
# 8   0  0  2 NA  1 NA
# 9   1  0  2  1  1  1
# 10  0  1  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: I corrected the 'dput' - thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for your code, it works on my test sample. I will apply it tomorrow on my whole dataset to check if there are additional problems. :)

Comment: Works also with my entire dataset. A short follow-up question: I tried to do this with lapply or mutate(across()), as it is recommended to avoid for loops in R. But if I need to evaluate i > V3, there is no way around a loop, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I used the loop - you've got two things changing, the column and the `i`, which makes those other options difficult. You could make it work with `mapply`, but this loop is so simple, I think using `mapply` (or `purrr::map2`) would make things less clear, so why bother?

Comment: Yep, the loop is pretty straight forward! Thanks again!